# how to extract hour and minute and groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 columns

```
Date            A   B
1/7/2016 8:00    0   0
1/7/2016 8:30    1   1
1/7/2016 9:00    2   1 
2/7/2016 8:00    0   0
2/7/2016 8:30    0   1
```

I would like to create a column C that extract only Hour and Minute, column D that groups column C and sums column A, column E that groups column C and sums column B

```
Date            A   B  C    
1/7/2016 8:00    0   0  8:00
1/7/2016 8:30    1   1  8:30
1/7/2016 9:00    2   1  9:00
2/7/2016 8:00    0   0  8:00
2/7/2016 8:30    0   1  8:30
```

Expected Output:

```
Time     D  E 
8:00     0  0
8:30     1  2
9:00     2  1
```

I tried:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
df['hour'] = df.date.apply(lambda x: x.hour)
```

I can extract hour but not hour and minute. Hope to hear some suggestions

Thanks,

Comment: What is your final expected output?

Comment: Based on this little example, it will have 3 rows grouping time in Hr-Min,  and 2 columns: D and E that is the sum of A and B

Comment: Also, notice that you've got a typo in your question data.  Column `'B'` fourth row is different in the initial dataframe from what it is when you print with column `'C'`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Alternative #1 (make Date a datetime column)

Assuming `df.Date` is `datetime`, you can access many vectorized datetime functions via the `dt` attribute.

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df['C'] = df.Date.dt.strftime('%-H:%M')
df
```

#### Alternative #2 (extract hour/minute using regex)

```
df['C'] = df.Date.str.extract(r'\s+0?(\d{1,2}:\d{2})', expand=False)
```

[image]

#### Result either way

Perform `groupby` then change names.

```
gdf = df.groupby('C')[['A', 'B']].sum()
gdf.reset_index().rename(columns=dict(C='Time', A='D', B='E'))
```

[image]

---

#### Timing of alternatives (100000 rows)

[image]

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared. I have to use `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], coerce=True)` before applying ` df.Date.dt.strftime('%-H:%M') `. Otherwise I will have an error: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`, and it also keeps Y-M-D in the dataframe. There are thousands of rows. I want to keep it short 48 rows (24hrs x 2), which also is the result of summing column A and B.

Comment: when u time something use more than a tiny sample ; your answer is completely misleading and others now have the impression that regex is actually stood solution (which it is NOT)

Comment: @Jeff that's fair. I'll update when I can and make sure to include more comprehensive testing in future posts.